# Performance issue loading data from CRM

Tags: c#, performance, linq, web, crm

Currently our website is facing a problem with slow response times (more than 1 min) when we query CRM from our website. We are using CRM 2011 though a web service. When we investigated we found that the time was spent at the point of querying CRM.

We have used the CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate our proxy classes that map to CRM entities. Then we create an instance of context and query CRM using LINQ with C#.

When we query, We load our parent object with LINQ to CRM and then we use LoadProperty to load the related children.

I would like to know if anyone out there using a different method of querying CRM, and if you have come across issues like this in your implementation.

I’ve included a simplified sample query below.

```
    public void SelectEventById(Guid id)
     {
            var crmEventDelivery = this.ServiceContext.EventDeliverySet.FirstOrDefault(eventDelivery => eventDelivery.Id == id);
            if (crmEventDelivery != null)
            {
              this.SelectCrmEventDeliveryWithRelationships(crmEventDelivery);
            }
    }

    private void SelectCrmEventDeliveryWithRelationships(EventDelivery crmEventDelivery)
     {
            // Loading List of Venue Delivery on parent crmEventDelivery thats been passed
            this.ServiceContext.LoadProperty(crmEventDelivery, Attributes.EventDelivery.eventdelivery_venuedelivery);

            foreach (var venueDelivery in crmEventDelivery.eventdelivery_venuedelivery)
            {
                 // Loading Venue on each Venue Delivery
                 ServiceContext.LoadProperty(venueDelivery, Attributes.VenueDelivery.venue_venuedelivery);
            }

            // Loading List of Session Delivery on parent crmEventDelivery thats been passed
            this.ServiceContext.LoadProperty(crmEventDelivery, Attributes.EventDelivery.eventdelivery_sessiondelivery);

            foreach (var sessionDelivery in crmEventDelivery.eventdelivery_sessiondelivery)
            {
              // Loading Presenters on each Session Delivery
              ServiceContext.LoadProperty(sessionDelivery, Attributes.SessionDelivery.sessiondelivery_presenterbooking);
            }
   }
```

Comment: I don't know about those specific services but if I were you probably start with those `foreach` statements. Normally when querying they result expensive. But, again, I'm don't know your service specifics.

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned on the other answers your main problem is the number of web service calls. What no one mentioned is that you can retrieve many objects with a single call using query joins. So you could try something like:

```
var query_join = (from e in ServiceContext.EventDeliverySet
                         join v in ServiceContext.VenueDeliverySet on e.EventDeliveryId equals v.EvendDeliveryId.Id
                         join vn in ServiceContext.VenueSet on v.VenueDeliveryId equals vn.VenueDeliveryId.Id
                         join s in ServiceContext.SessionDeliverSet on e.EventDeliveryId equals s.EvendDeliveryId.Id
                         where e.EventDeliveryId == id // *improtant (see below)
                         select new { EventDelivery = e, VenueDelivery = v, Venue = vn, SessionDeliver = s }).ToList();
```

Then you can run a foreach on query_join and put it together.

***improtant: do not use the base Id property (e.Id), stick with e.EntityNameId.Value (don't know why but it took a while for me to figure it out. Id returns default Guid value "00000..").

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you've provided this looks like a standard lazy-load issue, except my guess is that each lazy load is resulting in a web service call. This would be called a "chatty" service architecture. Your goal should be to make as few service calls as possible to retrieve data for a single request.

Calling to fill in details can seem like a good idea because you can re-use the individual service methods for cases where you only want data 1 or 2 levels deep, or all the way down, but you pay a steep performance penalty.

You would be better off defining a web service call that returns a complete object graph in scenarios like this. I don't know if/what you're using for an ORM layer within the CRM but if you make a specific call to fetch a complete graph of Deliveries then the ORM can eager-fetch the data into fewer SQL statements. Fewer calls to the web service (and subsequently fewer calls into the CRM's data store) should noticeably improve your performance.

Comment: When we had this problem we changed it to return IQuerable<T> instead of the T object itself, this allows your code outside your ORM to specifically mention which fields it needs through a LINQ .Select() call

Answer (score 1):

So I can see why this might take a while. I think as everyone else have commented you are making quite a few web service calls. If you get a moment it would be interesting to know if the individual calls are slow or its just because you are making so many, I would suggest profiling this.

In any case I suspect you would get better performance by not using the strongly type entities.

I would suggest using a FetchXml query, this will allow you to build a Sql Xml-Style query. Basically you should be able to replace your many we bservice calls with a single call. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328117.aspx) has an example, also check out the [Stunnware](http://www.stunnware.com/) FetchXml designer, Products > Stunnware Tools > Download and Evaluation. It was built for Crm 4 but supports virtually all the features you will need.

If you dont fancy that, you could also try a [QueryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328300.aspx) or [OData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767), both of which should allow you to get your data in one hit.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the suggested tips in the other answers and doing further profiling, in our particular scenario with our use of CRM, and how it was set up - we decided to simply **bypass it**.

We ended up using some of the in-built views, this is not a recommended approach in the CRM documentation, but we really needed to achieve higher performance and the CRM approach in this instance was just in our way.

*To anyone else reading this, see the other answers too.*

Answer (score 0):

Because the query does not know what fields will be needed later, all columns are returned from the entity when only the entity is specified in the select clause. In order to specify only the fields you will use, you must return a new object in the select clause, specifying the fields you want to use.

So instead of this:

```
var accounts = from acct in xrm.AccountSet
               where acct.Name.StartsWith("Test")
               select acct;
```

Use this:

```
var accounts = from acct in xrm.AccountSet
               where acct.Name.StartsWith("Test")
               select new Account()
               {
                   AccountId = acct.AccountId,
                   Name = acct.Name
               };
```

Check out this post more details.

[To Linq or not to Linq](http://superiorcrm.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/crm-to-linq-or-not-to-linq/)